# How to apply DataTable filter programmatically?

Tags: primefaces

Using the PrimeFaces Demo filtering [DataTable](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml) (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml) as an example, I would like to be able to provide "filtering" links outside of the table for the user to click (say Volvo, Forw, BMW, etc). When the user clicks the link, I would like to switch the selected item in the manufacturer filter dropdown and apply the filter. I haven't been able to figure out how to get to the filter properties to make the change. Can this be done via javascript? How do I access the selection list and set the current selection?

**UPDATE:**
Following Daniel's link, I managed to get the dropdown selection to change, but I am unable to get the filter to apply. In the columns where the filters are based on an input field, triggering the keyup causes the data to filter but I can't figure out what event to trigger on the select to make it filter. Here is the code I am using:

```
<p:commandLink id="filterLink" 
    value="Click to filter to Volvo Only" 
    onclick="$('#carForm\\:dataTable\\:manufacturerColumn_filter').val('Volvo'),
        $('#carForm\\:dataTable\\:manufacturerColumn_filter').trigger('filter')"
/>
```

The link created by the above will switch the Manufacturer filter to Volvo but will not cause the data to filter.

Comment: take a look at my approach: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8776589/617373 do the same for your filters...

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That was useful and I was able to apply the global filtering as you showed. I added an update showing the code I am attempting to use. I have not been able to figure out what the event is that i need to trigger in order to get the filtering to happen on a select.

Comment: You are welcome, b.t.w when you find someone question or answer useful to you you should click the ^ (arrow up) button (look at their tooltips)... in this case its both :)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I need to work on making that more of a habit whenever I am searching for information here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to call the filter event at the table level. So my code above should properly be:

```
<p:commandLink id="filterLink" 
value="Click to filter to Volvo Only" 
onclick="$('#carForm\\:dataTable\\:manufacturerColumn_filter').val('Volvo'), carsTable.filter()"
/>
```

Comment: don't forget to trigger 'keyup' on input element

Comment: In my case I wanted to trigger the filter from a commandlink outside of the table, not from an input element. The .filter() call causes the table to filter according to the value entered by the commandlink.