# primefaces global filter with commandlink

Tags: primefaces

Okay.  So I'm trying to implement a global filter using commandLinks.  The idea is to have an alphabet of commandLinks, which a user can then use instead of typing a letter.

So far, I've got filtering working on the column (will add the filterStyle none once the commandLinks are working).

Using chromes debug tool (ctrl-shift+i), and clicking on the command link, i can see the datatable refresh the list. However, it doesn't filter anything.

I've been using primefaces showcase, and this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883040/how-to-apply-datatable-filter-programatically) to base my code on, which is below:

```
 <p:dataTable id="availableSpecies" var="species" value="#{bbWizardBean.speciesPaletteList}"
                                    emptyMessage="Add First Species" dynamic="true"
                                    width="120"
                                    widgetVar="speciesPaletteVar"
                                    scrollHeight="250" scrollRows="20" scrollable="true"
                                    styleClass="width-fix-spcPal-ie" style="width:150px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
                                    filteredValue="bbWizardBean.speciesPaletteListFilter">

        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Species Palette" />
                            <p:commandLink id="globalFilter" value="A" onclick="$('speciesColumn_filter').val('A'),speciesPaletteVar.filter()"/>
        </f:facet>
        <p:column filterBy="#{species.speciesName}"
                                    headerText="Species" style="font-size:13px;" id="speciesColumn">
            <h:outputText id="dragIcon" value="#{species.speciesNameSmall}" style="font-size:11px; background-color:silver; cursor:move;"/>
            <h:outputText id="dragIconTooltip" value="..." title="Full Name: #{species.speciesName}" rendered="#{species.speciesNameLength > 10}"/>
            <p:tooltip for="dragIconTooltip" />

                            <p:draggable for="dragIcon" revert="true" />
        </p:column>
```

I've removed the rest of the table to make the codebase smaller. I think I'm screwing up the value I should set, but I'm not quite sure how. Any help would be appreciated! First post, so any suggestions to clean up the question is appreciate ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so for some reason (like i thought), the setting of the val for the filter wasn't working right.  You need to add two \'s before the : for some reason.  If anyone knows, that would be awesome, but the correct code is:

```
<p:commandLink id="globalFilter" value="A" onclick="$('#positiveRegulationForm\\:availableSpecies\\:speciesColumn_filter').val('A'),speciesPaletteVar.filter()"/>
```

Where
positiveRegulationForm is the top form
availableSpecies is the DataTable name
speciesColumn_filter is the filter for the column speciesColumn

Really curious as to why you need the two forward slashes

Comment: first `\` is to escape the `:` which otherwise will be interpreted as jQuery selector and the second `\` is to escape the first `\` ...

Comment: Oooohhh, Okay.  I've never used the jQuery selector before.  Thanks! Was wondering what i was actually escaping :p