# Filter in datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

[image: My data here]

I do demo on http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf but i want to move combobox to **New location** or i don't want it appear in new line, it mean the combobox stay in same line with the title's label!
Pls help me, thanks all suggest!

Comment: similar approach as in here http://stackoverflow.com/q/8776589/617373

Comment: Dear @Daniel, this is my code [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8U8aN.jpg but it not work pls sugget me idea, it's better if you guide me to do on combobox. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. I understand that you need the filter dropdown (it's not a combobox!) of the 3rd column to appear in the top header. But I don't understand what exactly you mean with "appear in new line" and what exactly you would like to do with the filter inputs in other columns.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC!, I want filter data of datatable from dropdown but the data in dropdown is not same table in database with data of datatable but the relationship based-on 1-n.

Comment: he actually wants to move the functionality of that "Manufacturer" column filter outside of the table to the "New location", where he can fire instant datatable filtering with the combobox, i would love to find a great answer from you BalusC.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to have the filter in the same line. First add `filterStyleClass` attribute to the column:

```
<p:column headerText="Manufacturer" filterBy="#{car.manufacturer}"   
          filterOptions="#{tableBean.manufacturerOptions}"  
          filterMatchMode="exact" filterStyleClass="inlineFilter">  
        <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />  
    </p:column>
```

And then addd folowwing CSS rule:

```
.ui-column-filter.inlineFilter {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Damian so much! Can you help me move the dropdown to new location or anywhere but it's still do filter.