# multiple f:facets for datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to use two f:facets: the first row one as a 'header' for the table containing only text, and the second row containing a 'global filter' (label + inputbox).

I have tried countless combinations but failed.

How can I achieve this with JSF/Primefaces?

Here is one example of what I tried:

```
<p:dataTable var="customer" widgetVar="customerTable" id="dataTable" value="#{customerbean.customerList}" paginator="true" rows="20" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50,100" emptyMessage="#{text['table.customer.filter.notfound']}" filteredValue="#{customerbean.filteredCustomers}" editable="true"> 
<f:facet name="header">                       
<h:outputText value="#{text['table.customer.header']}" />                            
</f:facet>
<f:facet name="header2">                       
<h:outputText value="#{text['table.customer.filter.global']}" />
<p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="customerTable.filter()" style="width:150px" />
```

This is my second attempt based on the answer below:

```
            <f:facet name="header">                    
            <p:columnGroup type="header">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column colspan="4">
                        <h:outputText value="#{text['table.customer.header']}" />    
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
                <p:separator/>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column colspan="4">
                        <h:outputText value="#{text['table.customer.filter.global']}" />
                        <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="customerTable.filter()" style="width:150px" />                         
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:columnGroup>                  
            </f:facet>
```

Whole datatable:

```
               <p:dataTable id="customersTable" var="customer" widgetVar="customerTable" value="#{customerbean.customerList}" paginator="true" rows="20" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50,100" emptyMessage="#{text['table.customer.filter.notfound']}" filteredValue="#{customerbean.filteredCustomers}" editable="true" draggableColumns="true" rowKey="#{customer.id}" selection="#{customerbean.selectedCustomer}" selectionMode="single"> 

                <f:facet name="header">                    
                    <p:columnGroup type="header">
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column colspan="4">
                                <h:outputText value="#{text['table.customer.header']}" />    
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>
                        <p:separator/>
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column colspan="4">
                                <h:outputText value="#{text['table.customer.filter.global']}" />
                                <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="customerTable.filter()" style="width:150px" />                         
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>
                    </p:columnGroup>                  
                </f:facet>

                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{customerbean.onEdit}" update="@this"/>  

                <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{customer.name}" filterBy="#{customer.name}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <p:cellEditor>  
                        <f:facet name="output">  
                            <h:outputText value="#{customer.name}" /> 
                        </f:facet> 
                        <f:facet name="input">  
                            <p:inputText value="#{customer.name}" style="width:100%"/>  
                        </f:facet> 
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>  

                <p:column headerText="CPR" sortBy="#{customer.cpr}" filterBy="#{customer.cpr}" filterMatchMode="contains">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{customer.cpr}" />  
                </p:column>  

                <p:column headerText="Passport No." sortBy="#{customer.passportno}" filterBy="#{customer.passportno}" filterMatchMode="contains">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{customer.passportno}" />  
                </p:column>  

                <p:column headerText="DOB" sortBy="#{customer.dob}" filterBy="#{customer.dob}" filterMatchMode="contains">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{customer.dob}" />  
                </p:column>   

                <p:column headerText="Options" style="width:50px">  
                    <p:rowEditor />  
                </p:column>                  

                <f:facet name="footer">  
                    There are #{fn:length(customerbean.customerList)} customers in total.  
                </f:facet>  
            </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: What table component are you using?

Comment: As indicated in the table, datatable. I've also edited my code.

Comment: In case you want to get the global filter out of the table , take a look at this :  http://stackoverflow.com/q/8776589/617373

Comment: I can see where this has its uses but I would prefer not to customize to such an extent. In case of new versions, changes, etc. I would have to go back and change this.

Comment: @javaMS If the last comment is refered to my comment than know this : my solution works since 3.0 till now (3.4 without any changes at all - its just uses basic jquery)

Answer (score 3):

You can't name the facet with whatever name you want. It must be something that the datatable *understands*. It *understands* "header", just like it *understands* "footer", but not "header2" or "footer2".

That said, you can use only one `<f:facet name="header">` and inside that you can do whatever you want. You may use a `<p:panelGrid columns="1">`, or a `<p:separator>`, or even a simple table, it's just html/css formatting, like you would do anywhere in your page.

---

There's also a more complex way, if you want to try a little bit harder, using `<p:columnGroup type="header">` and many `<p:row>`s inside it, for example:

```
<p:columnGroup type="header">
   <p:row>
      <p:column>
         <f:facet name="header">
             <h:outputText value="Your header" />
         </f:facet>
      </p:column>
   </p:row>
   <p:row>
      <p:column>
         <f:facet name="header">
             <h:outputText value="Filter: "/>
             <p:inputText value="#{filter}">
         </f:facet>
      </p:column>
   </p:row>
</p:columnGroup>
```

[See a full example here.](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableGrouping.jsf)

Comment: thanks, this helped alot but I am forced to use a separator otherwise I get everything concatenated after eachother. Is there a way to make the two things (header + global filter) on a row each?

Comment: If you don't want to mess around with html/css formatting, use the second approach. I don't think that teaching html/css formatting is in the scope of the answer.

Comment: I did use the second approach, and posted my code in the original question. My question is how to NOT use a separator and achieve a separate row for the header and the global filter? I dont want to mess with CSS/html.

Comment: @javaMS Do **not** use `<f:facet>` around `<p:columnGroup>`.

Comment: If I do that, then it all stops working, i.e. no headers or facet shown.

Comment: @javaMS Then there is something really wrong with your datatable. What version of primefaces are you using? [See the full example here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableGrouping.jsf), and check if you're doing anything wrong other than the columnGroup.

Comment: Ive been following that example, unfortunately I cannot get further. I am now using the separator since I see no other solution.

Comment: @javaMS Maybe you should add to your question the whole `p:dataTable` code? I feel we are taking blind shots here.

Comment: It has been there for some time now... let me know in case you come up with anything. For now, I am using the separators.